# Comparing query parameter to selector class for click action

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of divs that on click of each will show another div. I currently have a script that will take the query parameter value `(e.g: http://domain.com/?id=1)`, strip the value of the `id` and use that value to trigger the corresponding div with that number as a class. My current implementation is:

```
var param = window.location.search.split('?id=')[1];
  if(param == 1){
    $(".1").click();
  }
  else if(param == 2){
    $(".2").click();
  }
  else if(param == 3){
    $(".3").click();
  }
  else if(param == 4){
    $(".4").click();
  }
  else if(param == 5){
    $(".5").click();
  }
  else if(param == 6){
    $(".6").click();
  }
  else if(param == 7){
    $(".7").click();
  }
  else if(param == 8){
    $(".8").click();
  }
  else if(param == 9){
    $(".9").click();
  }
  else if(param == 10){
    $(".10").click();
  }
});
```

I have tried to create a loop to go through all of the selectors:

```
var array = [];
$('.list-group li').each(function(idx, el){
    array.push(el);
});
```

but I'm having trouble figuring out how to compare the value of the query parameter to a value in the array and select the array value to trigger the class. One of the main reasons for simply looping over the list-group is the event that there are more than 10 items. I may be over thinking this functionality, and could just use the original implementation, but think this could be cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you already have var 
so you can simply do ,

`var param = window.location.search.split('?id=')[1];
$('.'+param).click();`

no need to create a new array

Comment: That's the idea I was thinking of! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of the `if` statement by building your selector string as follows:

```
var param = window.location.search.split('?id=')[1];
$("." + param).click();
```

i.e.

- get the param number
- select all elements with class value that the param evaluated to
- call the `click()` method on the selection

Answer (score 1):

Try to create the selector based on the input parameter first, then check if such a div exists, and if yes, call its `click` method:

```
    var id = window.location.search.split('?id=')[1]; // grab the input
    var selector = '.' + id;                          // construct the selector
    var div = $(selector);                            // search for the div
    if(div.length > 0) {                              // check if the div is found
        div.click();                                  // perform the click
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an array of class names:

```
if( divClasses.indexOf(param) > -1 ){
  $("."+param).click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var array = [];
$('.list-group li').each(function(idx, el){
    array.push(el);
});
var param = window.location.search.split('?id=')[1];
param = parseInt(param);
if(param && array[param]) {
    array[param].click();
}
```